# Android - Observable List

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, observablelist

Is there any observable list in Android? `ObservableList` class doesn't exist! I want to have a list that if any item changes occurred, notify me to update views.

**Note:** If there's no native way, please teach me how to implement one using `RxJava` if it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People who faced this problem could use [my implementation of `ObservableList`](https://gist.github.com/meNESS/e3cd620cd71270a20816e015d78792cd) which uses `RxJava`.

Thanks to [Daniel Zolnai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395437/daniel-zolnai) and [Maurice Gavin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1500317/maurice-gavin).

Answer (score 0):

There is one in Apache Commons.
You can add it to your project by adding

```
compile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2'
```

To your dependencies.

Comment: Is it possible to do this by using `RxJava`? If yes, can you help me with that please?

Comment: Thanks for giving the right solution (the given link). I posted the right answer here and I mentioned you and Maurice Gavin for helping me :)